# Is there a way to show all the kills of a team in one scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having trouble making a scoreboard that shows all of the collective kills from every person on the team, not just the individual players, is there an easy way of doing this? And to be specific, I'm talking about in the sidebar.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 3):

First, make a score to store kills, `/scoreboard objectives add kills playerKillCount` Then make a fake player to store the team kills, so for team red for example: `/scoreboard players set Red teamKills 0`.

Lastly, you will have a small command chain for each team. It will make each player on the team add their kills score to the team total, then reset their kills score:

```
/scoreboard players operation Red kills += @a[team=red,score_kills_min=1] kills
/scoreboard players reset @a[team=red,score_kills_min=1] kills
```

And of course you will want to display it in the sidebar: `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar kills`

Comment: In this case `/execute` is not needed and would only cause more work to be done by the server; you can swap out the first command for: `/scoreboard players operation Red kills += @a[team=red,score_kills_min=1] kills`

Comment: I have been using execute alot lately for comparing scores in cases where I did need it, so much to the extent that I forgot you do not always. Thanks for pointing that out, it is now fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

El Six's answer above mostly works on Minecraft Java Edition 1.16.5, but needs a few adjustments for consistency:

**Step 1**: Make a custom objective called "kills", which will be tied to Minecraft's built-in "playerKillCount" attribute which tracks player kills automatically. Note that you can use "totalKillCount" here instead if you also want to track ALL mobs + players that were killed instead:

```
/scoreboard objectives add kills playerKillCount
```

**Step 2**: Create a dummy player "RedTeam" to track kills for the "red" team, initialize it to 0 so it will show on the board later:

```
/scoreboard players set RedTeam kills 0
```

**Step 3**: The first command will add the player kills from "red" team members to the custom "RedTeam" marker, which we will see on the sidebar. The second command resets the players' individual kill scores, which keeps them from showing on the board and also makes sure we don't add team kills more than once. **Loop these commands through a command block or data pack or script for each team:**

```
/scoreboard players operation RedTeam kills += @a[team=red] kills

/scoreboard players reset @a[team=red] kills
```

**Step 6**: Track the kills for "RedTeam" on the visible sidebar scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar kills
```

You will know that this worked if you see the "RedTeam" getting tracked as in the picture below.

**If you need to test team scores solo (without any other players), consider replacing "playerKillCount" with "totalKillCount" -- this will allow you to kill mobs and see your team score increase.**

[image]